# Selenium WebDriver not able to identify the WebElements on a JSP page(hidden frames??)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble identifying the username and password input elements on a JSP Page. I feel it might have frames with no frame ID. Below is the HTML source. Selenium not able to identify the DIV ID(mainContent).

Comment: is this code in a frame block? currently there is not any frames. and, what is your xpath code?

Comment: I do not see any explicit iframe. Here is the xpath I have used.                      //  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
 //   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")));
 // Page.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys("Demo");

Comment: it is working. what is the exactly problem?

Comment: I get "Unable to locate the element: username" error message.

Comment: Selenium is not able to recognize the username and password input elements and also the SIgnIn button located on the login page. Actually there are few hyperlinks on the login page. Selenium is not able to identify any element on the entire page. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: i write your code in a sample page: http://www.mahsumakbas.com/selenium/so.html can you run your code for that link?  now, i can access to username and password and can sendkeys.

Comment: I can access the username and password from mahsumakbas.com/selenium/so.html. But it failed from my website. Just to let you know, there is some javascript on the page. Do you think that is causing trouble. I could paste the entire HTML source, if it helps.

Comment: Ok. Can you send it?

Comment: Try using web developer tools to identify if there are any frames on the page. If not, you can use the javascript executor to send text to the fields via javascript.

Comment: Firebug not able to identify any frames on the page.

Comment: I get "null" after running the following Javascript.

Comment: WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('username');");
   System.out.println(element);